# How to Check Double value is Null or Zero in kotlin

Tags: if-statement, kotlin, double

How to Check Double value is Null or Zero in kotlin

```
val ratio:Double? = 0.0

val calRatio = if (ratio == null || ratio == 0.0)
        0.12
    else
        ratio
```

ratio in null , 0.0 , 0.1

if ratio null or 0.0 then return 0.12

and ratio is 0.2 or more then return same ratio value

how to check this algorithm not use if statement

Comment: Why would you not want to use an if statement?

Comment: Even if you do for some reason want not to use an if statement in particular, this is an if expression, not an if statement.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can write this in idomatic Kotlin without an `if` statement using [`takeUnless`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-unless.html).

```
val ratio: Double? = 0.0
val calRatio = ratio.takeUnless { it == 0.0 } ?: 0.12
```

The `takeUnless` call checks whether the number matches the predicate `it == 0.0`. If the predicate evaluates to `true`, `null` is returned. Only when the predicate evaluates to `false` is the actual number returned.

We can see why this works by considering the three possible cases:

1. When `ratio` is `null`, the predicate `it == 0.0` evaluates to `false`. The call to `ratio.takeUnless { it == 0.0 }` returns the value of `ratio`, which is `null`. Because its left-hand-side operand is `null`, the `?:` operator returns the right-hand-side value of `0.12`.
2. When `ratio` is `0.0`, the predicate `it == 0.0` evaluates to `true`. The call to `ratio.takeUnless { it == 0.0 }` ignores the value of `ratio` and instead returns `null`. Because its left-hand-side operand is `null`, the `?:` operator returns the right-hand-side value of `0.12`.
3. When `ratio` is any non-null, non-zero number, the predicate `it == 0.0` evaluates to `false`. The call to `ratio.takeUnless { it == 0.0 }` returns the value of `ratio`, which is the original number. Because its left-hand-side operand is not null, the `?:` operator returns the left-hand-side value.

Comment: I'd favor using takeIf insteaf of takeUnless in order to improve readability. When reading code I believe it's much easier to see positive statements. In my opinion ratio.takeIf { it != 0.0 } ?: 0.12 is easier to understand than ratio.takeUnless { it == 0.0 } ?: 0.12